# Using @keyframes with inline style binding

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am making a scrolling slider inside a component in Vue.js without jQuery so it is Javascript & CSS only. I wanted to make the slider dynamic so that if I add an extra image the div with the slider just gets bigger. So to make it dynamic I use javascript to get the width of the div and want to use this to set the width. And now my question is how can i bind this width to the @keyframes while still compatible with IE 10 & 11.

in the vuejs component:

```
<div id="slider1" class="s-carousel-section">
    <div class="s-image-carousel s-image-carousel-first" v-bind:style="{}">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x320" alt="foto">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x320" alt="foto">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt="foto">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt="foto">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x320" alt="foto">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x320" alt="foto">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x320" alt="foto">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x320" alt="foto">
    </div>
    <div class="s-image-carousel s-image-carousel-second">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x320" alt="foto">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x320" alt="foto">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x320" alt="foto">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt="foto">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt="foto">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x320" alt="foto">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x320" alt="foto">
        <img class="s-carousel-logo rounded mr-16" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x320" alt="foto">
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the javascript I use to get the width of the slider(I use imagesloaded so that I get the width of the images when they are loaded)

```
imagesloaded(document.getElementById("slider1"), () => {
      var sliderWidth = document.getElementById("slider1").scrollWidth;
});
```

And as last the css to make the slider move

```
@keyframes first {
  0% { 
    transform: translateX(0px);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  99.99% {
    transform: translateX(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes rest {
  0.01% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  0.011% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-1000px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```